# What is the word for someone who wants to get the most out of his life?

Tags: single-word-requests

The phrase "to live fully" comes to mind, but is not quite what I'm looking for. I'm writing user stories in the form of

> As a  ______  [word], I want this and that, because I will lose less time.

so the intended usage is describing a customer or a user who wants to get the most out of his time and life, who wants to live his life to the fullest.

Alternatively, if this is too narrow, is there a word for someone who in general wants to get the most out of things he has or things he endeavors?

Comment: You could say they "live like they are dying", meaning they do not think about what they may regret, but try to get the best out of the time they have left.

Comment: Something like [epicurean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/epicurean)?

Comment: This isn't clear. You seem to say you want to live life fully (which is vague but I understand to mean 'filled with activity' or 'lots of interesting things', but then your sentence mentions 'losing less time' which sounds more like optimizing use of time. Those don't sound like the same things to me (though they overlap). Do you want efficient use of time, or do you want extraordinary things to happen?

Comment: @Lawrence seems similar to "hedonistic" and both seem somewhat one-dimensional to me.

Comment: @Mitch "to lose time" was meant in the sense of not spending time in a personally satisfying or fulfilling way or in a way that leaves the person regretful having spent it the way they did.

Comment: @Houndolon Responding to your comment to Lawrence, well, both heodnism and epicureanism are personal philosophies that match 'live life to its fullest' as you've described. Yes, they both have connotations and nuances you may not be thinking of but that's part of the long intellectual commentary on those philosophies. I take it you want something less...selfish?

Comment: @Mitch I'm thinking more of fulfilling instead of pleasurable. E.g. someone who has a noble cause, like helping the poor, who might live his life to the fullest without enjoying many pleasures during life.

Comment: @Houndolon Oh. OK. But that is important nuance you need to add to your question. Please edit.

Comment: Maybe *Mame*: ["Life is a banquet, and most poor sons of bitches* are *starving* to death! Live!](https://books.google.com/books?id=rPTHHaDUOdEC&lpg=PP1&dq=auntie%20mame&pg=PA298#v=onepage&q=%22a%20banquet%22&f=false)" *"suckers" in the film version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say they have [**a lust for life**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lust%20for%20life), which connotes a strong desire to live a full and rich life.

> - "She had a lust for life like no one I have ever met."

A person who has a lust for life usually has a vitalizing energy, radiates [***joie de vivre***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/joie+de+vivre) and enjoys life fully.

Comment: "Having lust for life, I want..." I like it!

Comment: That's not a word to describe the person itself.

Comment: [pleasurist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleasurist) might fit the bill. "One who is devoted to worldly pleasure."

Answer (score 5):

**bon vivant**

*noun*

> person who enjoys the good things in life, especially good food and drink; a man about town.

[en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_vivant)

Comment: This fits but I'd find it pretty funny if I came across the expression in a user story in a software requirements system, which seems to be what the OP was after.

Comment: @StuartF - Oddly enough, i never noticed that was the intended use case :-)

Answer (score 4):

How about **ambitious go-getter**

Merriam Webster defines **[ambitious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambitious)** as follows:

> 1.  having or controlled by ambition**;**  having a desire to be
>       successful, powerful, or famous
>   2.  having a desire to achieve a particular goal
>   
>  Example**:**  an ambitious young executive

The same dictionary, i.e. M.W. define **[go-getter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-getter)** as follows:

> an aggressively enterprising person

Merriam Webster, once again, defines **enterprising** as follows:

> marked by an independent energetic spirit and by readiness to act 
>  Example**:**  an enterprising young reporter

Based on all of the information furnished, if you find the suggested phrase of interest, then you could rewrite the sentence as follows:

> As an ambitious go-getter, I want this and that, because I will lose less time and it would increase my chances of success.

Answer (score 4):

Henry David Thoreau coined the phrase "living deliberately", as a descriptor for one who tries to be conscious at all times and avoid living passively.

> “I went to the woods because I wished to live deliberately, to front only the essential facts of life, and see if I could not learn what it had to teach, and not, when I came to die, discover that I had not lived.”

Answer (score 3):

A [go-getter](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-getter) is what I'd call someone like that.

Answer (score 3):

To "**live like there's no tomorrow"?**

Answer (score 2):

In your situation I would go with *Efficient*.

> **Efficient**,
>   Acting or producing effectively with a minimum of waste, expense, or unnecessary effort.
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficient

Used as [So that I am efficient].

---

In life as a whole, *Ambitious* might be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something like "busy [user/customer]", or "[user/customer] whose time is precious". Generally speaking that seems to get the point across without sounding bombastic.

Answer (score 1):

How about a **Biophile**?

> #### Biophile
>
> 1. One who feels a strong attraction for or emotional attachment to the living world.
> 2. A person who loves life or living systems.

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biophile))

It does lean more towards living things, like nature, but I see no reason why it can describe someone who generally loves all aspects of life, thus leading to a full living of it. It describes a person who exhibits **Biophilia**:

> #### Biophilia
>
> - An innate love for the natural world, supposed to be felt universally by humankind

([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/biophilia))

Answer (score 0):

**lifehacker**

> lifehack
>
> A tool or technique that makes some aspect of one's life easier or
>   more efficient.
>
> Web sites now exist, where lifehacker (followers of the movement) can
>   trade
>   lifehacks - suggestions on how to reduce chaos and make their lives
>   more enjoyable.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/tags.php?tag=lifehacker)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a case for using [Self-actualized.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-actualization)

[Self-actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization) is a term from psychology which was popularized in the 1950s and 60s by Abraham Maslow as part of his [heirarchy of needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow's_hierarchy_of_needs), however it has been popularized by self-help literature, and is often found in seminars on self-improvement. The basic idea is that self-actualization is the achievement of one's full potential by making best use of opportunities and experiences for personal growth. It often includes creative ventures, and may also include altruistic efforts to help others achieve the same status.

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Dictionary Online:

> (noun) **pleasure seeker**
>
> a person in search of amusement or enjoyment
>
> example sentence: *‘in recent years, the island has been a magnet for pleasure seekers’*

The English translation of the French nouns 'un jouisseur', 'une jouisseuse', from the verb 'jouir', 'to enjoy' in English, 'an enjoyer', if it existed.